# Can I ask a question as part of another sentence, like in "I think she's nice what do you think?"?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

Is asking questions in a middle of a sentence grammatically correct for example

> I think she's nice what do you think?

That's correct or should I make two sentences out of that?

Comment: *You don't **make** them two sentences! They **are** two sentences!* Same as the first two sentences in this comment. You can blur the distinction with a dash instead of a full stop / exclamation mark, but reducing it to just a comma is a very "minimalist" modern writing style that might lose you marks in an exam. And no punctuation at all between the assertion and the question would *definitely* lose marks in an exam.

Comment: The comment by FumbleFingers is correct. A native speaker would have a clear pause after "nice", indicating that the statement was complete. And the following question would most likely have emphasis on "you".  "What do *you* think?" And that emphasis would signal, in case there was any doubt, that the question is alluding to the previous assertion, "I think she's nice".

Comment: I have edited my answer, incorporating the earlier comments here.

Answer (score 0):

Edit

Your example has a missing punctuation mark, like a semicolon or something as strong.
It would be fine as

> I think she's nice; what do *you* think?

There will likely be an emphasis on *you* to contrast that with the *I* in the preceding clause.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it as two distinct sentences. Your re-cast is more awkward.

Comment: Thanks, @DoneWithThis.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: It's all the same, whether it's a full stop, a semi-colon, or an em-dash.  These are two distinct independent clauses, connected semantically.  You could call the question a supplemental question, since it is anchored semantically to the first clause.